# Checking the length of the arrays(instance variables) in rpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Having 2 arrays in `index` method, I want to test the equality of the arrays' lengths but it's not working (the lengths of the arrays are equal after testing manually)

```
def index
    @countries = get_countries()
    @capitals = get_capitals()
end
```

Rspec file:

```
describe CountriesController do 
  describe 'index' do
    it 'countries.length == capitals.length' do
      expect(assigns(countries.length)).to eq (assigns(capitals.length))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`rspec\` - comparing two arrays' lengths against each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579733/rspec-comparing-two-arrays-lengths-against-each-other)

Answer (score 1):

```
describe CountriesController do 
  describe 'index' do
    it 'countries.length == capitals.length' do
      expect(assigns(:countries).size).to eq (assigns(:capitals).size)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe CountriesController do 
  describe 'index' do
    it 'has a country for each capital' do
      #create 3 countries here something like
      3.times do 
       Country.create(capitol: :capitol)
      end

      get :index

      expect(assigns(countries.length)).to eq (assigns(capitals.length))

    end
  end
end
```