# `rspec` - comparing two arrays' lengths against each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Having 2 arrays in `index` method, I want to test the equality of the arrays' lengths but it's not working (the lengths of the arrays are equal after testing manually)

```
def index
    @countries = get_countries()
    @capitals = get_capitals()
end
```

Rspec file:

```
describe CountriesController do 
  describe 'index' do
    it 'countries.length == capitals.length' do
      expect(assigns(countries.length)).to eq (assigns(capitals.length))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you are making a request to that action... that is.. where is the `get :index` call?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
describe CountriesController do 
  describe 'index' do
    it 'countries.length == capitals.length' do
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:countries).length).to eq assigns(:capitals).length
    end
  end
end
```